# Remap shortcut to a single key cannot be used

Tags: shortcut-keys, configuration, system-settings

I want to remap my workspace switcher shortcut to a single key, specifically the <kbd>Page Up</kbd>/<kbd>Page Down</kbd> keys for going to the top/bottom workspace. But Ubuntu will not let me do this using **System settings > Keyboard > Shortcuts**, giving the following warning:

> The shortcut "Page up" cannot be used because it will become impossible to type using this key.
>   Please try with a key such as Control, Alt or Shift at the same time.

Is there any other way to remap shortcuts to a single key?
Help is appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is actually quite easy using the [xbindkeys [image: Install xbindkeys]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/xbindkeys) and the [xdotool [image: Install xdotool]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/xdotool) packages. `xdotool` lets you emulate key presses, and `xbindkeys` lets you add custom shortcuts.

All the following steps are run in a terminal.

First we will kill the process

```
killall xbindkeys
```

Now we put our custom shortcuts in the `~/.xbindkeysrc` file

```
gedit ~/.xbindkeysrc
```

and we put in the following lines

```
"xdotool keyup Next && xdotool key ctrl+alt+Down"
   Next

"xdotool keyup Prior && xdotool key ctrl+alt+Up"
   Prior
```

save and close, and start `xbindkeys` again by running

```
xbindkeys
```

It should now work like you wanted, enjoy!

---

**Explanation:**
Now what does it actually do? Say, you press <kbd>Page Up</kbd>, your computer recognizes this as the `Prior` key (you can check this using `xev | grep key` and pressing keys). Now before we simulate other keypresses, we should emulate a key release first, that's what the `xdotool keyup Prior` is for. If it is released successfully then we send the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd> combination and this is what `xdotool key ctrl+alt+Up` is for.

Comment: I recommend using `touch .xbindkeysrc && xbindkeys -f .xbindkeysrc` to create the config file so you don't get any of `xbindkeys` default bindings.

Comment: @Seth Thanks nice suggestion, updated the answer. You don't need the `-f .xbindkeysrc` though, since it is the default.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to remap any navigation command in GNOME and Unity directly with [dconf](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/dconf-tools/) or via command line using gsettings. For PageUp/PageDown moving workspace up/down you could do:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-up "['Page_Up']"
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-down "['Page_Down']"
```