# How to remap a single function key f1-f12, without any new program?

Tags: shortcut-keys, function-keys

Variants of this question have been asked before, e.g., ["Remap shortcut to a single key cannot be used"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/249760/remap-shortcut-to-a-single-key-cannot-be-used). The answer usually involves installing some other package. Is it possible to map/remap a single function key (I have F10 to switch windows in mind)? I have tried the [official Ubuntu way](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/keyboard-shortcuts-set.html.en) and it won't allow this. I also tried this command:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-windows "['F10']"
```

That won't work either. I want to map it in such a way that the operating system shortcuts should take precedence over all other program shortcuts (like when in Emacs).

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. The reason why the `org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings` may not have been working is that I had no `gnome.desktop`. I used the dconf editor to browse the org entry and realised, it should have been `org.<desktop_env_name>.` and so forth. Anyways, use the dconf editor and it lets you bind any keys. Obviously now, *be careful!*